# How to use "&" correctly in an URL in C?

Tags: c

I want to call an URL in a C program which contains some "&". The system only recognices the URL until the "&" (https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr) and tells me it doesnt know the command cht and chl. How can I make it to use the whole URL?

```
char get_qr[100];
sprintf (get_qr, "start https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=Hello World!);
system (get_qr);
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual code which compiles?

Answer (score 3):

The issue isn’t the URL handling, it’s that you’re launching a shell command via `system`.

Shell commands need to be *shell quoted*. In particular, `&` is a special character *of the shell*. So put quotes around your shell command argument:

```
system("start \"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&chl=Hello World!\"");
```

(In your code there’s no need for `sprintf` anyway. If your *actual* code requires `sprintf`, don’t just allocate a static buffer; allocate a dynamic buffer of the correct size!)

Comment: `start` makes me thing of Windows, so I would use double quotes...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Damn, I was thinking of that and then used single quotes anyway. You’re of course right!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I use double quotes like you suppose it doesnt open the browser anymore but a terminal window instead. Is there a way how to tell the system that it needs to open the url in the browser?